# Cannot resolve method onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, methods

Im trying to create an application that allows sharing images and videos from gallery into facebook. There is error popping up in my coding in this lines (highlighted in red) : "onActivityResult", "getContentResolver", "PlusShare", "setType", "addStream", "setText" and "getIntent" saying cannot resolve method. Full coding as follows:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dothis.facebook;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQ_SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private static final int REQ_START_SHARE = 2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);

    // listeners of our two buttons
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Button shareMediaButton = (Button)    findViewById(R.id.share_media);
            shareMediaButton.setOnClickListener(new   android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent photoPicker = new     Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    photoPicker.setType("video/*, image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(photoPicker, REQ_SELECT_PHOTO);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int   resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            if (requestCode == REQ_SELECT_PHOTO) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
                    String mime = cr.getType(selectedImage);

                    PlusShare.Builder share = new  PlusShare.Builder(this);
                    share.setText("hello everyone!");
                    share.addStream(selectedImage);
                    share.setType(mime);
                    startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(),   REQ_START_SHARE);

                }
            }
        }

    }
   }
```

Android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dothis.facebook" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"  />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone guide me on how to solve this problem? Any kind of suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code , hope it helps.

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/path/to/image.ext"));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to modify your `Manifest.xml` file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
```

Then modify your Method like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            taken = true;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);
                imagePhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Image has been saved to " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " as " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            taken = false;
            Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Action canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Where you call the intent to use the came enter this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "picture.jpg");
uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
```

i used those values to make it work

```
private static final int REQ_CODE = 1152;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You quote `{}` is in wrong place, your `onCreate` method
anonymous class `View.OnClickListener` didn't close the with `}` properly.

Below is the fixed version with the quote placed correctly.

```
package com.example.dothis.facebook;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static final int REQ_SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
  private static final int REQ_START_SHARE = 2;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);

    // listeners of our two buttons
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Button shareMediaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_media);
        shareMediaButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPicker.setType("video/*, image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPicker, REQ_SELECT_PHOTO);
          }
        });

      }
    };
  }


  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == REQ_SELECT_PHOTO) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        String mime = cr.getType(selectedImage);

        PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
        share.setText("hello everyone!");
        share.addStream(selectedImage);
        share.setType(mime);
        startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), REQ_START_SHARE);

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you @Derek Fung. The onActivityResult and getContentResolver is without error now but  "PlusShare", "setType", "addStream", "setText" and "getIntent" are still highlighted in red and im unable to run the activity. Is there any suggestion for that.

Comment: this is the error message :   :app:compileDebugJava
/Users/geraldgoh/AndroidStudioProjects/Facebook/app/src/main/java/com/example/dothis/facebook/MainActivity.java:51: error: package PlusShare does not exist
                PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
                         ^
/Users/geraldgoh/AndroidStudioProjects/Facebook/app/src/main/java/com/example/dothis/facebook/MainActivity.java:51: error: package PlusShare does not exist
                PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(this);

Comment: You have to import the PlusShare

Comment: add the line `import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusShare;`  below `import android.widget.Button;` if you are trying to use the `PlusShare` in Google API

Comment: im sorry but i would actually like to share the contents in Facebook..so means the coding is wrong is it? @Derek Fung. sorry still new to android development.

Comment: I guess you might have wrongly copy some code on the web, you should take a look at the official page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: You can raise a new question if you encounter problem in implementing the Facebook Share